# How to do balancing on blazor server using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, session, blazor, load-balancing

I have a website on blazor server that will need to scale in the future i.e. there will be several servers. How to do balancing on blazor server using Nginx? In this case, it is necessary that the session is also saved, i.e. did not throw out in case of turning off one of the servers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft describes how to load-balance on Linux using NGINX on the following page:

[ASP.NET Core SignalR hosting and scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-3.1#linux-with-nginx)